# F_SETPIPE_SZ undelcard with android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, pipe

I'm building a jni lib for android using NDK, I need to change pipe buffer size, but `fcntl(pipe_fd[0], F_SETPIPE_SZ, 1048576);`
compiling failed, errror message "F_SETPIPE_SZ undelcard", I already added #define _GNU_SOURCE at the beginning of the C++ source file. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is that you never ended your `#ifndef` for `_GNU_SOURCE`, since you state that you have included it at the beginning. Here is an example of what your files should look like that need access to that macro:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <fcntl.h>

extern "C"
{

int test()
{
    int some_fd = 123456;
    int size_in_bytes = 12345;
    return fcntl(some_fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, 12345);
}

} // End extern

#endif
```

Checked against the following versions

```
Android Studio: 1.3.2
NDK: r10e
```

Various gradle settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried on a Ubuntu server, just `#define _GNU_SOURCE` will do, but failed with android NDK

Comment: @skipper You are saying this does or does not work? I get it to compile using Android Studio on API 14.

Comment: Any reason you are using such an old NDK? This has been verified with:
`Android Studio: v1.3.2
NDK: vr10e`

Comment: Got no choices, company code, But I finally get it work by directly adding the following lines:
`#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define F_SETPIPE_SZ        (F_LINUX_SPECIFIC_BASE + 7)
#define F_GETPIPE_SZ        (F_LINUX_SPECIFIC_BASE + 8)`